# How to use multiple syncronized threads to sort an array?

Tags: java

I want to sort an array using multiple syncronized threads. For example I want to use at least 
2 threads to sort the array and another thread to show me at some moments the situation of sorting. Some ideas please?

Comment: THe idea here would be: Write some code and ask us if you have specific problems.

Comment: Two synchronized Threads are equal to one Thread. Isn't it?

Comment: @Martijn, no. You can think of two synchronized threads as two threads which have no race conditions.

Answer (score 3):

You can employ JSR 166y Fork Join framework to do parallel merge sort. You can see examples [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp03048.html) and [here](http://blog.quibb.org/2010/03/jsr-166-the-java-forkjoin-framework/).

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at:

```
java.util.Arrays.sort();
```

It doesn't use 2 threads - but how can that possibly be a requirement?